# Остаться на той же странице после ее перезагрузки

Tags: html, javascript, css

Хочу реализовать идею, как это сделано здесь

`http://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/i136562/monitor-dell-24-ultrasharp-u2412m.html#comment`

Есть вкладки описание, характеристики, отзывы ... . 
Сделать легко так: создать несколько дивов, одному дать display:block, другим display:none и по скрипту менять их местами. 
Но после перезагрузки страницы таким образом, вклада будет возвращаться на первоначальную.
Заметил что в адресную строку попадает параметр через #.
К чему он относится, и как все это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Сделай через hash](http://javascript.ru/window-location)

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать через :target css

```
.show_when_active {
    display: none;
}
.show_when_active:target {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/8gRHc/