# После перезагрузки страницы остаться на той же вкладке

Tags: javascript, html

Есть две кнопки (вкладки) контент которых помещается в div и при выборе другой вкладки удаляется. То есть что-то по типу табсов. Нужно сделать так, чтобы после перезагрузки страницы оставалась выбранная до этого вкладка. Подскажите как это реализовать с localStorage?

js:

```
document.querySelector('.burger-menu__nav').addEventListener('click', event => { //переключение вкладок
  if (event.target.innerText.trim() === 'Buttons') {
        delElements();
        buttons();
  }
  if (event.target.innerText.trim() === 'Create table') {
    delElements();
    create_table_form();
  }
})

function delElements() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.divAdd div').forEach(function (a) {
    a.remove()
  })
}

function create_table_form() { //содержимое вкладки Create table
    let div_table = document.createElement('div');
    div_table.className = 'table_div';
    var addDiv = document.querySelector("div.divAdd");
    addDiv.appendChild(div_table);

    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.innerText = "Table creation";
    div_table.appendChild(h1);

    let p_width = document.createElement("p");
    p_width.innerText = "Table width:";
    div_table.appendChild(p_width);

    let width_input = document.createElement("input");
    width_input.type = "text";
    width_input.id = "width";
    div_table.appendChild(width_input);

    let p_height = document.createElement("p");
    p_height.innerText = "Table height:";
    div_table.appendChild(p_height);

    let height_input = document.createElement("input");
    height_input.type = "text";
    height_input.id = "height";
    div_table.appendChild(height_input);

    let btn_crt_table = document.createElement("button");
    btn_crt_table.innerText = "Create Table";
    div_table.appendChild(btn_crt_table);
    btn_crt_table.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        draw_table(width_input.value, height_input.value);
    });

    let sect = document.createElement('section');
    sect.id = "section";
    div_table.appendChild(sect);
}

function buttons() { //содержимое вкладки Buttons
    let div_btns = document.createElement('div');
    div_btns.id = "btnss"
    div_btns.className = 'btns';
    var addDiv = document.querySelector("div.divAdd");
    addDiv.appendChild(div_btns);

    var h1 = document.createElement("H1");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Buttons");
    h1.appendChild(t);
    div_btns.appendChild(h1);

    let p_color = document.createElement("p");
    p_color.innerHTML = "Choose color: ";
    div_btns.appendChild(p_color);

    let inpt_color = document.createElement("input");
    inpt_color.id = 'idColor';
    inpt_color.setAttribute("type", "color");
    div_btns.appendChild(inpt_color);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let btns = document.createElement("button");
        btns.className = "buttons";
        btns.innerHTML = "Click me :)";
        div_btns.appendChild(btns);
    }
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>FRONT-END LAB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="burger-menu">
                <a href="#" class="burger-menu__button">
                    <span class="burger-menu__lines"></span>
                </a>
                <nav class="burger-menu__nav" id="burger-menu__nav">
                    <a href="#" class="burger-menu__link">Create table</a>
                    <a href="#" class="burger-menu__link">Buttons</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <div class="divAdd"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [После перезагрузки страницы оставаться на активной вкладке (tabs)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1459739/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5-tabs)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin но без подходящего ответа

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы реализовать это, можешь в момент смены вкладки добавить запись в localStorage текущей вкладки:

```
if (event.target.innerText.trim() === 'Buttons') {
    delElements();
    buttons();
    localStorage.setItem('tab', 'buttons');
}
```

И при загрузке странице добавить условие рендера вкладки:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('tab') === 'buttons') {
    // рендерим вкладку с кнопками
    buttons();
}
```

Но лучше, конечно, делать через [hash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/249817/%d0%9e%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8?rq=1).